# Using React to post and update count in client component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Cannot seem to get this `onClick` button to work and update the "kudos given" number. Basically 3 .js files, while using [this API](https://github.com/promantek/kudoserver) to test. My code is:

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import KudoList from "./components/KudoList";

import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    contacts: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://kudos-devtech8-yvbvpoek.herokuapp.com/users")
      .then(response => {
        const newContacts = response.data.map(c => {
          return {
            id: c.id,
            name: c.username,
            fname: c.first_name,
            lname: c.last_name,
            kgive: c.kudos_given_count,
            kreceived: c.kudos_received_count
          };
        });

        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          contacts: newContacts
        });

        this.setState(newState);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to our Kudo app</h1>
        </header>
        <KudoList contacts={this.state.contacts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The Contact.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Contact.css";

class Contact extends React.Component {
    state = { kgive: 0,
              fname: '',
              lname: '',
              kreceived: ''
    };

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.incrementKudoCount = this.incrementKudoCount.bind(this);
    }

    incrementKudoCount(ev) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        kgive: prevState.kgive+ 1,
      }));
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="appPerson">
          <p>Name: {this.props.fname} {this.props.lname} <button onClick={() => this.incrementKudoCount()}>Give Kudo!</button></p>
          <p>Kudos Given: {this.props.kgive}</p>
          <p>Kudos Received: {this.props.kreceived}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Contact;
```

And then the KudoList.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Contact from "./Contact";

function KudoList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.contacts.map(c => <Contact key={c.id} name={c.name} fname={c.fname} lname={c.lname} kgive={c.kgive} kreceived={c.kreceived} /> )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default KudoList;
```

I get no errors, but the button binding event is not working correctly and not sure why. Should I have a separate component to give kudo or can't it be as easy as I have it with a little modification?

Comment: try onClick = {this.incrementKudoCount}

Comment: @HemaNandagopal - doesn't solve it. Not sure why though....

Comment: Everything seems to be okay , could you add it to some github repo or in codepen?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal - it is all there at the top in the 3 files. Nothing more than that and nothing more complex.

Comment: In Contact component, when you click, you change kgive in state but you display kgive in props. Why ??? You should use react-dev-tools and check kgive value in state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event listener should be a function. I see that you are returning (invoking ) the function.
Just `onClick={this. incrementKudoCount}` should work.

**UPDATE : A working Sandbox ** (As stackoverflow sandbox doesn't support imports)
https://codesandbox.io/embed/j2w729p329

Comment: that does not do it. Nothing happens when that is done.

Comment: The reason for that is, you are updating the state and rendering the props. You might need to refer `this.state.kgive` in render in contacts.js rather than `this.props.kgive`

Comment: not sure I am clear what you mean there? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Mark I have did this in the sandbox code.[ https://codesandbox.io/embed/j2w729p329] Creating the sandbox as stackoverflow compiler doesn't support multiple file.

Comment: weird as the only thing different between your code there and mine is the addition of `{" "}` after the lname value I have in there. Why is that (if you know)? That being said, if I now wanted that count to persist to the API and following this flow, couldn't I simple use `axios` and a `.post` in there?

Comment: @Mark I made two changes. 1. onClick event I just passed the clickHandler function. 2. In render method, you were referencing `this.props.kgive` I made it to `this.state.kgive`